# In te.cl type http request smuggling, how is the packet length in the smuggling request calculated?

Tags: request-smuggling

i am studying "[Exploiting HTTP request smuggling to bypass front-end security controls, TE.CL vulnerability](https://portswigger.net/web-security/request-smuggling/exploiting/lab-bypass-front-end-controls-te-cl)"，I found that the length can be set to 20, 30, etc. It seems that within a certain range, I can set the value of Content-Length at will[image][image],I think it should be 6, it should be 6 for "x=1\r\n0", but when the Content-Length is set to 6, the response result is wrong. So, how is the value of this Content-Length calculated? I didn't find the answer online, can anyone help me, thank you very much

Did a test based on "Steffen Ullrich"'s answer, it looks like there is a problem with the test
[image]

I did a test based on regilero's answer, and it seems that there are some problems
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

When the smuggling attack occurs the chunked mode is ignored (CL:4 is applied).
So we remove the first 4 bytes (71\r\n).
Then you have a new request which is a 'simple' POST. I do not count 6 characters (and not 5 either, as `x=1\r\n` is 5) but **10**:

```
x=1\r\n
0\r\n
\r\n
```

`0\r\n\r\n` is the end of chunk  of the first request, but it's only used as end of chunk for actors which have no issues, if you have the cl-te issue then this end of chunk is now part of your body, you need to add these 5 bytes to you original body size.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to set the `Content-Length` to 10, but it didn't trigger the vulnerability. On the contrary, if it is set to 15, it can trigger the vulnerability. Do you know why this happens?I wrote the test results in my post, you can take a look

Comment: Sorry, I have no deep knowladge of this exercise, and the precise attack you are trying. But in this situation I would open Wireshark, and check every requests/responses, especially between the Proxy and backend (if there's a proxy, but usually it's needed for a smuggling attack). By using a longer Content-length you may end up in a situation where you have unterminated requests, so someone may be waiting for more content. Always restart everything when you messed up the sizes.

Comment: The problem with request smuggling is that the front-end and back-end process data differently. You can’t see the data processing at the back-end with wireshark, right? @regilero

Comment: If you are in a lab, with access to the backend, you can extract a tcpdump there. Then read it in wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

The body of the inner request is `x=1`, not `x=1\r\n0`. The `\r\n0` is part of the chunked encoding of the outer request instead: the`\r\n` is at the end of each chunk but does not belong to the payload itself. The following hex number (and following `\r\n`) describes the length of the next chunk, i.e. 0 in case of the last chunk. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding) about the details of chunked encoding.

Thus the content-length should be 3.

Note that the chunk size given before the chunk should reflect the actual size of the chunk. With a `content-length: 30` this was 114, i.e. 71 in hex as given. With a `content-length: 3` this needs to be adjusted to 113, i.e. hex 70.

Comment: I think you are right. I tried to send the request many times, but the "delete" keyword did not appear in the response result. It seems that this method cannot launch an effective attack. I re-edited the post and put the test results. Can you Give more explanation? Thanks again

Comment: are you telling me that the backend server received `x=1`?
Maybe you can read this article: https://paper.seebug.org/1048/#34-te-cl, according to this article, the backend server should receive `x=1\r\n0\r\n`, that's why I thought `Content-Length` should be 6 (effective content is `x=1\r\n0`). These two statements seem contradictory, which confuses me, Can you give a more detailed explanation?@Steffen Ullrich

Comment: @ppxisppx: the site you refer to does not make much sense to me since it ultimately issues a POST request without any kind of length information about the body (i.e. no content-length, no transfer-encoding chunked). The content-length should describe how much body you want the server to see. If you want `x=1` to be seen then the content-length should be set to 3.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I understand what you mean, but when the `content-length` is set to 3, from the test results, it fails, why is this so? @Steffen Ullrich

Comment: @ppxisppx: what do you mean with "it fails"? What is your expectation, what do you get instead? Does it work as you expect for other values, i.e. is your expectation correct?

Comment: What I expect is that I can access the `admin` directory through the request smuggling vulnerability. I don’t understand why I can’t access the `admin` directory when the `content-length` is set to 3, but I can successfully access the `admin` directory when it is set to 15.